# Вызов метода при запуске spring web

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

У меня есть web-приложение на spring. Мне необходимо при его запуске дёргать метод, чтобы выполнить определённый круг задач. Также мне необходим доступ к `ApplicationContext` Spring. Как данное реализовать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В Spring есть такие понятия как **контейнер** и **Bean**. Под контейнером подразумевается DI контейнер, этакая сущность, которая хранит в себе все сервисы и объекты, которые могут понадобиться приложению - вместо того, чтобы создавать их каждый раз, их можно создать один раз и сохранить в *контейнере*, чтобы отдавать по требованию. Под Bean подразумевается любой экземпляр класса, который должен оказаться в контейнере (и неявно подразумевается, что он должен существовать в единственном экземпляре - в контейнер *можно* поместить несколько экземпляров одного класса, но это сопровождается болью), и Bean может быть вообще чем угодно - классы, аннотированные `@Service`, `@Component`, `@Controller`, `@Repository` считаются за бины, причем все эти бины - и это уже напрямую относится к вопрсу - создаются не по требованию, а при загрузке приложения, то есть ваша задача решается через создание бина, который будет загружен при загрузке самого приложения (на самом деле правильно все делать через `@PostConstruct` или `InitializingBean`, но об этом позже).
Кроме того, контейнер занимается *разрешением зависимостей* - именно он подставляет те свойства и параметры, которые отмечены как `@Autowired` и `@Value`, во время создания экземпляра бина, в том числе, он способен рекурсивно создавать бины, чтобы разрешить зависимость высокого порядка. С помощью этого механизма (`@Autowired`) можно получить `ApplicationContext`.
Чтобы выполнить какие-либо действия после инициализации приложения (вам лучше не мешать своими методами запуску Spring - он предоставляет возможность выполнить код после инициализации фреймворка, но до запуска приложения), вам нужно прямо сказать об этом Spring (а не выполнять какую-либо логику в конструкторе бина). Для этого можно аннотировать произвольный метод бина как `@PostConstruct`, либо реализовать интерфейс `InitializingBean` и соответствующий метод `afterPropertiesSet()`:

```
public class Abc implements InitializingBean {
    public void afterPropertiesSet() {
        LOGGER.info("Look, mum, i'm running in late initialization stage!");
    }
}
```

Что по поводу `ApplicationContext`, то его можно получить с помощью аннотации `@Autowired`:

```
public class Abc implements InitializingBean {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public void afterPropertiesSet() {
        LOGGER.info("This is context, isn't it?", applicationContext);
    }
}
```

остается только добавить сам бин в приложение тем или иным способом.
xml-way:

```
<bean id="abc-bean" class="my.super.package.Abc"/>
```

java-way:

```
@Component
class Abc {
    ...
}
```

**Attention:** однако, скорее всего, вам не нужен контекст вообще. **Скорее всего, вам нужно с помощью того же `@Autowired` получить какие-то другие зависимости**, и тогда от использования контекста следует отказаться. Если вам нужно на ходу использовать контейнер для создания экземпляров классов с некоторыми зависимостями из контейнера, то для этого можно использовать `AutowireCapableBeanFactory` и ее метод `autowire()`.

**update** пример простого менеджера

```
@Component
class PollingAdapterManager {
    private Map<String, SourcePollingChannelAdapter> mapping = new HashMap();

    public SourcePollingChannelAdapter createAdapter(String key) {
        SourcePollingChannelAdapter adapter = new SourcePollingChannelAdapter();
        mapping.put(key, adapter);
        return adapter;
    }

    public SourcePollingChannelAdapter getAdapter(String key) {
        return mapping.get(key);
    }

    public void discardAdapter(String key) {
        mapping.remove(key);
    }
}
```

Comment: А вы написали, что хранить экземпляры одного класса, это боль, можно обосновать? Просто у меня храниться большое кол-во экземпляров класса: `SourcePollingChannelAdapter` и от этого не уйти...

Comment: @Wolkodav вероятнее всего, вам не нужно их хранить в контейнере. Боль в том, что основной идентификатор для подтягивания бинов из контейнера - это класс бина, и если там несколько экземпляров, то контейнер без дополнительной помощи не может разобраться, что ему возвращать, и стреляет исключением. Т.к. в цикле разработке обычно появляются еще инстансы, то ситуация имеет тенденцию часто повторяться.

Comment: Смотрите, я в определённый момент создаю `SourcePollingChannelAdapter`, запускаю его. На определённое действие мне необходимо остановить его. Как это сделать, если  не хранить в контейнере?

Comment: @Wolkodav хранить в сервисе, который ими управляет.

Comment: А можете пример? Просто списком?

Comment: @Wolkodav привел простейший пример

Comment: Хмм, хорошо, примерно я так и представлял это себе... А синхронизировать не надо вставку и удаление? Ведь туда могут писать несколько пользователей? Просто у меня веб-приложение.

Comment: Это простейший пример. Надо, если у вас возможен конкуррентный доступ.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо.

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26272/discussion-between-wolkodav-and-etki).